# How to load SearchResultsTableView same as TableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller, custom-cell

I am new to ios development.
I have a tableview(with customcell) in a viewcontroller(not TableViewController). I have added searchDisplayController through storybaord. I am able to get the searchresults, but the problem is the searchresultstableview and actual tableview are not same. I am not able populate the searchresultstableview with custom cell. Here is the code I am posting.

Please don't mark my question as duplicate, cause I have checked many of the questions/answers and they are based on TableViewController(not a normal ViewController with tableView)

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
         return [filtArr count];
    }
    else 
    {
        return [myTestArr count];
    }

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cCell"];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[CustCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault       reuseIdentifier:@"cCell"];
    }

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {

   //This line is showing the searchResultsTableview(but not customcell)
   //cell.textLabel.text= [filtArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    //No results and normal searchResultsTableview
    cell.myLab.text = [filtArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }

    else
    {
        cell.myLab.text = [myTestArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    return cell;
}

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope

{    
     [filtArr removeAllObjects];

     NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",searchText];
     NSArray *tempArray = [myTestArr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];

     filtArr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:tempArray];
}



- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:
    [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:    [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: It seems you return the same cell for both `searchDisplayController` and normal view controller . and you do not need to hide searchDisplayController's searchResultsTableView in it's delegate method.

Comment: @johnMa, I removed the line self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.hidden=YES;